# Spatial Join for analysing the distance between point and polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, distance, proximity

I already read the article of ArcGIS several times, but I dont come to a solution.

I want to create a tool for the valuation of properties for the use of windenergy. I am very close to the finish and now I am stuck where I want to calculate the distance between a point and different polygons.

In the picture is the example. I have the little point and want to know how far it is away from the green and how far from the purple polygon.

Is spatial join the right way?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Barbara Hö! Try using the [Near](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) tool.

Comment: Do you want distance to the centre of the polygon or simply distance to the nearest node/vertex on the polygon?

Comment: How many points are you talking about, you only show two? If it is that many why not simply use the measure tool and measure manually?

Comment: Near tool only finds the closest feature. Generate Near Table, provides distance to all features within the near_distance.

Comment: By "article" do you mean documentation?  If so, which page(s) of documentation are you reading?